# Игнорирует мой шрифт в CSS и берет шрифт Bootstapp

Tags: html, css

Хочу добавить шрифт OpenSans на свой сайт.

Добавил в свой сайт Bootstrap - для адаптивной верстки.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Так же подключаем css от бутстрапа, **ссылку на наш шрифт** и наш css сверху

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site2.css" />
```

И в нашем кастомном css пишем в конце

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important,  sans-serif; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Вроде как должен быть везде наш шрифт теперь. Но! Нет, что-то переопределяет мой css и в отладчика я вижу следующее

```
inherited From Body
_reboot.scss
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
```

Этот _reboot.scss - часть бутстрапа, я так понял. Но почему он игнорирует мой css и пользуется бутстрапом? И как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что любой селектор имеет приоритет выше чем у звёздочки, это относится и к селектору `body` тоже

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bad * {
  font-family: Arial !important, sans-serif; 
}

.good * {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important; 
}

.bad div, .good div {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="bad">
  <div>Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="good">
  <div>Foo</div>
</div>
```

Модификатор !important относится ко всему свойству, а не к одной из частей его значения.